# AutoIt script suddenly stopped working correctly after 2 months; misclicking

Tags: autoit

I have a script that will automatically populate actions of all the textboxes in my Bluebeam PDF.  Please keep in mind I have just started working with AutoIT. 
 Here is the code for reference:

```
#region --- Au3Recorder generated code Start (v3.3.9.5 
KeyboardLayout=00000409)  ---
Global $textBoxNumber = InputBox("Text box number", "Enter the number of text 
boxes.                      (three character max)", "", " M3")
Global $textBoxCounter = 1
Global $downVariable = ''
Global $documentName = InputBox("Document Name", "Enter the document name.", "", " M50")
#region --- Internal functions Au3Recorder Start ---
Func _Au3RecordSetup()
Opt('WinWaitDelay',100)
Opt('WinDetectHiddenText',1)
Opt('MouseCoordMode',0)
Local $aResult = DllCall('User32.dll', 'int', 'GetKeyboardLayoutNameW', 'wstr', '')
If $aResult[1] <> '00000409' Then
  MsgBox(64, 'Warning', 'Recording has been done under a different Keyboard layout' & @CRLF & '(00000409->' & $aResult[1] & ')')
EndIf

EndFunc

Func _WinWaitActivate($title,$text,$timeout=0)
    WinWait($title,$text,$timeout)
    If Not WinActive($title,$text) Then WinActivate($title,$text)
    WinWaitActive($title,$text,$timeout)
EndFunc
#include <String.au3>
_AU3RecordSetup()


Do
   _WinWaitActivate($documentName,"")
MouseClick("left",1785,822,1)
_WinWaitActivate("Action","")
MouseClick("left",72,55,1)
MouseClick("left",521,103,1)
_WinWaitActivate("JavaScript Editor","")
MouseClick("left",269,125,1)
Send("var txtField = event.target{ENTER}txtField.fillColor = color.yellow;")
MouseClick("left",331,248,1)
_WinWaitActivate("Action","")
MouseClick("left",516,410,1)
_WinWaitActivate($documentName,"")
MouseMove(1792,795)
MouseDown("left")
MouseMove(1788,796)
MouseUp("left")
MouseClick("left",1748,873,1)
MouseClick("left",1759,820,1)
_WinWaitActivate("Action","")
MouseClick("left",75,51,1)
MouseClick("left",469,95,1)
_WinWaitActivate("JavaScript Editor","")
MouseClick("left",222,84,1)
Send("var txtField = event.target{ENTER}txtField.fillColor = 
color.transparent;")
MouseMove(320,253)
MouseDown("left")
MouseMove(320,252)
MouseUp("left")
_WinWaitActivate("Action","")
MouseClick("left",497,403,1)
_WinWaitActivate($documentName,"")
MouseClick("left",232,995,2)
MouseClick("left",232,995,2)
MouseClick("left",232,995,2)
MouseClick("left",232,995,2)
MouseClick("left",232,995,2)
MouseClick("left",232,995,2)
MouseClick("left",232,995,1)
MouseMove(234,995)
MouseDown("left")
MouseMove(233,222)
MouseUp("left")
MouseClick("left",69,225,1)

   $textBoxCounter += 1
   $downVariable = _StringRepeat("{DOWN}", $textBoxCounter)
   Send($downVariable)


Until $textBoxCounter = $textBoxNumber + 1
#endregion --- Au3Recorder generated code End ---
```

I had been using it for over 2 months and having it pretty much do my work for me as I sit back, working smarter not harder.  All of a sudden when I went to use it yesterday it got to the 10th text box and quit on me, clicking in random space, pausing the script.  I have tried it multiple times, even rewriting the code, but this error seems to come up every time.

Why would this be happening?

Comment: has there been any change in environment recently? EG Windows Update or other software update? Code does not just do something different without code changing for no reason.

Comment: I considered that too, I have not updated AutoIT.  Only things that has been updated since then would be Bluebeam and the general windows updates. I went from Bluebeam Revu, to Bluebeam Revu eXtreme.

Comment: I would suggest using pixel grabbers to get the correct locations, I believe AutoIT ships with this feature IIRC. See if the coordinates you get are the same as previous.

Comment: I have completely re assigned all the points, recording it over again and it still has the same outcome.  The points are in the right spot because the first 9 times through the loop it works correctly, hitting all the right locations, and for some reason miss-clicks the 10th 11th or 12th time through the Do- until statement.  Its strange how it is inconsistent on when it messes up the click.